# apply formatter only on edited code - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, save, formatter

I have implemented a formatter in eclipse for my code, when I try to save the changes it applies formatting on complete file.

Is it possible to apply formatter only on the **changed code** insted of full file?

@Edited

I want to apply this formatter on my existing files on save.
suppose i have a file with 10 methods and approx 1000 lines. I have added a new method in that file and apply the save. Then I want my formatter to apply formatter only for new added method not for the existing 10 methods.
I have to do it with each and every file in my project.
`@formatter:off` annotation can't help here.

Comment: That answer doesn't solve my problem. Please look at the updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, under preferences:
Java -> Editor -> Save Actions

"Perform the selected actions on save" -> "Format source code" -> Change from "Format all lines" to "Format edited lines"